# custom/Extend Microsoft 365 copilot

Tags: microsoft-teams

Title: Steps for customizing Microsoft Copilot for an app with multiple APIs connected to AWS
I have an app running with more than 1 API and connected to AWS.

What are the steps I need to follow, and which one should I use: Graph Connector or Plugin? Can I use both of them simultaneously? Can I use Copilot in my custom website?

I'm looking for guidance on customizing Microsoft Copilot for my app, which is currently running with multiple APIs and connected to AWS.

I'm unsure about the steps I need to follow and which tool to use - the Graph Connector or the Plugin. Additionally,

I'd like to know if it's possible to use both of them simultaneously. Lastly, I'm interested in understanding if I can integrate Copilot into my custom website. Any insights or best practices on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Discussion/opinion questions, as well as recommendation questions, are expressly off-topic here. Best to take the [tour], read [ask], and then how to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

1. Microsoft Graph connectors provide a platform for you to ingest your unstructured, line-of-business data into Microsoft Graph, so that Copilot for Microsoft 365 can reason over the entirety of your enterprise content. Content ingested through Graph connectors is added to the Microsoft Graph; this unlocks semantic understanding of your users' prompts in Copilot for Microsoft 365.
   Read More here: [Microsoft Graph Connectors for Microsoft Copilot
   for Microsoft
   365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365-copilot/extensibility/overview-graph-connector)
2. [Bot based Message extension plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365-copilot/extensibility/overview-message-extension-bot) support single bot API endpoint which internally can call multiple API Endpoints. We are also going to support [API-based message extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/build-api-based-message-extension?tabs=visual-studio-code%2Cnew-api) to support multiple endpoints.

Please go through [Extend Microsoft Copilot for Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365-copilot/extensibility/) documentation.